# Should I use a comma?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, punctuation, commas, sentence

Which is correct?

- Forgive, but don't forget.
- Forgive but don't forget.

I have researched this and found unclear answers.

Comment: The commaless version might be considered unusual as most writers would like to signal a pause (to show reflection, or to add contrastive drama) between the two jussives/hortatives. But it's not incorrect. Some might even want a weightier separator – a dash or ellipsis. None is incorrect. Older books on punctuation (and usually grammar)  and people who've read nothing on the matter since might disagree.

Comment: You, should, use, commas, until, you',re, commatose,!

Answer (score 0):

I should say with comma.
But I must admit there are no clear rules. Not in English but neither in many other languages.
Common advise:
Put a comma before but if you hear a clear pause or change in tune while reading out loud.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, janhgm! I'm afraid your answer has so many mistakes that its advice may not be deemed trustworthy.